# Why is "#.id" a bad selector in CSS/jQuery yet it works in an HTML anchor?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors, css-selectors, fragment-identifier

I'm using JSDoc. It generates ids with a period as in

```
<a id=".someMethodName"></a>
```

If another part of the page has

```
<a href="#.someMethodName"></a>
```

That works perfectly. Clicking the second anchor scrolls to the first.

But, neither `document.querySelector` nor jQuery will find the anchor.

Why does the browser itself accept this anchor but jQuery and querySelector do not?

```js
test("document.querySelector('#.someMethodName')", function() {
  document.querySelector('#.someMethodName');
});
test("$('#.someMethodName')", function() {
  $('#.someMethodName');
});

function test(msg, fn) {
  try {
    var result = fn();
    log(msg, result);
  } catch(e) {
    log(msg, e);
  }
}

function log() {
  var pre = document.createElement("pre");
  pre.appendChild(document.createTextNode(Array.prototype.join.call(arguments, " ")));
  document.body.appendChild(pre);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#.someMethodName">click here to go to anchor and see errors</a>
<pre>
put
some
text
here
so
the
page
is
long
enough
that
when
we
click
the
anchor
the
browser
has
as
a
place
to
scroll
that
is
off
screen
otherwise
we'd
have
no
way
to
see
if
it
worked
or
not
</pre>
<a id=".someMethodName">we should scroll to here</a>
<p>did we make it?</p>
<hr/>
```

Comment: A dot has a specific meaning in a selector: it indicates the following word is a class name.

Comment: `'#\\.someMethodName'`

Comment: I'd venture that this is a terrible design decision by the creators of JSDoc.

Comment: @cst1992: Please don't waste the time of reviewers with "funny" edit suggestions. [SO is the place where we hate fun](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/01/stack-overflow-where-we-hate-fun/).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

HTML5 permits having a period in an ID attribute value, and browsers have handled this without any issues for decades (which is why the restriction in HTML 4 — itself defined not by HTML but by SGML on which it is based — was relaxed in HTML5, now free from the legacy baggage of SGML). So the problem isn't in the attribute value.

The grammar of a fragment identifier as defined by [RFC 3986](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt) is:

> ```
> fragment    = *( pchar / "/" / "?" )
> ```

Where the character set of `pchar` includes the period. So `.someMethodName` is a valid fragment identifier, which is why `<a href="#.someMethodName">` works.

But `#.someMethodName` is not a valid *selector*, and the reason is twofold:

1. An ID selector consists of a `#` followed by an ident, and [an ident in CSS cannot contain a period](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#value-def-identifier).
2. The period is therefore reserved for a class selector (which similarly consists of a period followed by an ident).

In short, the parser is expecting a CSS ident after the `#` but not finding one because of the `.` that directly follows it, making the selector invalid. This is surprising because the notation of an ID selector is in fact based on the URI notation for a fragment identifier — as evident in the fact that both of them start with a `#` sign, as well as the fact that they are both used to reference an element *uniquely identified* within the document by that identifier. It's not unreasonable to expect anything that works in a URI fragment to also work in an ID selector — and in most cases it *is* true. But because CSS has its own grammar which doesn't necessarily correlate with the URI grammar (because they're two completely unrelated standards<sup>1</sup>), you get edge cases such as this one.

As the period is part of the fragment identifier, you will need to escape it with a backslash in order to use it in an ID selector:

```css
#\.someMethodName
```

Don't forget that you need to escape the backslash itself within a JavaScript string (e.g. for use with `document.querySelector()` and jQuery):

```
document.querySelector('#\\.someMethodName')
$('#\\.someMethodName')
```

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Several years ago a [W3C Community Group](https://www.w3.org/community/cssselfrags) was formed (of which I am a member) around a proposal known as *Using CSS Selectors as Fragment Identifiers* that, as you can imagine, married the two technologies in an interesting way. This never took off, however, and the only known implementations are some browser extensions that probably aren't even being maintained.</sub>

Answer (score 15):

For [HTML5](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute) is a valid id attribute:

> **There are no other restrictions on what form an ID can take**; in
>   particular, IDs can consist of just digits, start with a digit, start
>   with an underscore, consist of just punctuation, etc

Since it isn't a valid [CSS identifier](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#value-def-identifier), in order to use it with `querySelector()` or `$()` you should escape it like this:

```
#\\.someMethodName
```

[Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector#Notes):

> To match ID or selectors that do not follow the CSS syntax (by using a
>   colon or space inappropriately for example), **you must escape the
>   character with a back slash**. As the backslash is an escape character
>   in JavaScript, if you are entering a literal string, **you must escape
>   it twice** (once for the JavaScript string, and another time for
>   querySelector):

Be conscious that it isn't a valid [HTML4](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-id) id attribute

Comment: @tac What should be reported to them? That their code conforms the the html 5 spec, works in all browsers but isn't valid html 4?

Comment: @CodesInChaos *"Be conscious that it isn't a valid HTML4 id attribute"*. The OP's question clearly shows this is unintuitive, breaking behaviour that makes applying JQ or CSS a pain.

Comment: @tac: How is that the fault of either the authors of JSDoc, or the HTML Working Group? The HTML 4 id attribute wasn't even designed with CSS or jQuery in mind - the restriction comes from the NAME token in SGML, which was designed *years* before either of those two things even existed. It's pretty obvious that these IDs were intended to be named anchors and nothing more - and as already mentioned in my answer (the only one to do so), `.someMethodName` is a totally legal URI fragment identifier. Requesting that the IDs be changed just to make it easier for *you* to write selectors is asinine.

Answer (score 2):

You have to escape `.` with `\\` before querying for elements.
Replace

```
document.querySelector('#.someMethodName');
```

To

```
document.querySelector('#\\.someMethodName');
```

Also note that technically, for [HTML 4](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-id) required ID value format  is specified below:

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

So `.[A-Za-z]` is invalid one..

Comment: This was superceded **many** years ago by the HTML5 spec, which removed those restrictions (in deference to the fact that browsers never imposed them, and people happily ignored them). The only requirement in HTML for the `id` attribute is that it cannot have any spaces in it, and must be unique.

Answer (score 2):

### Regarding HTML5 ID naming conventions

---

In HTML5, you can [name your ID attributes anything you want](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute) with little to no restrictions on syntax:

> There are no other restrictions on what form an ID can take; in particular, IDs can consist of just digits, start with a digit, start with an underscore, consist of just punctuation, etc

## What selector functions are expecting

---

However, when using JavsScript selectors such as [Document.querySelector()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector), it's important to note the syntax of *how* it evaluates its arguments.

> Returns the first element within the document (using depth-first pre-order traversal of the document's nodes|by first element in document markup and iterating through sequential nodes by order of amount of child nodes) that matches the specified group of selectors.
>
> element = document.querySelector(selectors);
>
> - `element` is an element object.
> - `selectors` is a string containing one or more CSS selectors separated by commas.

## When you confuse the selector functions

---

So here, we see that it's attempting to parse [CSS selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_Started/Selectors). Basically, the function interprets any string starting with a `#` as a *class* and any string starting with a `#` as an *id*, so when you try to pass it a string like this:

`#.someMethodName`

It thinks you're trying to parse an id *and* a class all as a single argument, and throws an error calling it a syntax error.

## In Conclusion

---

So in conclusion, while your ID values are technically valid, using `.` and `#` will confuse those JavaScript selector functions like `$(selector)` and `document.querySelector(selector)` etc.

To remedy this issue, you need to let the function know that you're trying to use `.` or `#` as a character instead of an identifier by escaping the non-identifier character(s):

```
#\\.someMethodName
```

[**Working demo of this in action**](https://jsfiddle.net/wcbdbomo/)

Answer (score 2):

> Why does the browser itself accept this anchor but jQuery and querySelector do not?

Because the hash isn't a CSS selector, it's a `#` followed by an ID.

The browser happily scrolls to that element because it isn't using the hash, unchanged, as a CSS selector. It's probably not using a CSS selector at all, but rather its internal method for looking up elements by ID — the one that is also called by `document.getElementById`, which also doesn't care about the dot. Proof:

```js
document.getElementById(".someMethodName").style.color = "green";
```

```html
<div id=".someMethodName">I'm green because I was found by <code>document.getElementById(".someMethodName")</code></div>
```

While it's true that CSS uses a `#` to mark the beginning of an ID selector, that doesn't mean every `#` everywhere is the beginning of a CSS ID selector.

If the browser *did* use the hash as a CSS selector, it would presumably escape it correctly prior to using it.

Comment: ... in which case it wouldn't *really* be using it as a CSS selector :P +1